# How to create new items within a view Create in ASP.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I know it's a basic issue in MVC, but cant I found a simple way to accomplish this task. Within a view create (like Create User), I need to add some new items to a combobox where I select the permission level for this user. How to do this without the need to cancel the action of the inclusion of the user, create the desired level in a separate view and then create the User with the newly created level?

Comment: I am not sure I am following you.

Comment: you are not clear man, do you need a select input inside your create view? is this the poblem that you need to know how to do that? if so, let us know

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this by using ajax javascript. You post the data to the server and use the data you get back in your form / view.

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

[Basic example at codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/JQuery-AJAX-with-ASP-Net.aspx)

[Posting form using ajax](http://weblogs.asp.net/mikebosch/archive/2008/02/15/asp-net-mvc-submitting-ajax-form-with-jquery.aspx)

Comment: Hello Morph. I'm not sure if this is the solution. Is there any way to do this with partialview? I need something like:
<code><div class="editor-field">
                            Origem:
                            <%:Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ModelObject.IdOrigem, 
                                    new SelectList(Model.OficioOrigemInfoList, "Id", "Nome")) %>
                            <%:Html.ValidationMessage("Origem", "*") %>
                            <%:Html.ActionLink("Nova Origem", "CreateOrigem", new { model = Model.ModelObject })%>
                        </div></code>